# Floor and ceiling of Numbers

Tags: java

Ask a user for a number then print the ceiling and floor.

if we insert 4.66 means it should produce output as 5 and 4 ..but it produces 
5.0 and 4

```
class Challenge{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter a number:"); 
        double dob=scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Math.ceil(dob));
        System.out.println(Math.floor(dob));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)):

> ```
> public static double ceil(double a)
> ```

`Math.ceil` returns a `double`, so it's normal that the printed value is `5.0` and not `5`. You'll have to cast it to `int`.

```
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(dob));
```

It's the same for `floor`.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/JRUSlM)

Answer (score 0):

Both `Math.ceil(dob)` and `Math.floor(dob)` returns `double` values then those are print as `5.0` and `4.0`

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil(dob));// double value output
System.out.println(Math.floor(dob));// double value output
```

You can use followings to take `5` and `4`

```
System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(dob)); // int value
System.out.println((int)Math.floor(dob)) // int value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double ceil(double a)
public static double floor(double a)
```

From the return you can see that it returns double